# Можно ли ограничить диапазон значений масштаба?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Можно ли ограничить масштаб, чтобы при его увеличении(например) он не мог стать больше чем заданное значение? Чтобы мой сайт нельзя было увеличить до масштаба в 250%, а только в 200%.

Comment: Никак. Нужно не запрещать фундаментальные вещи а верстать с учётом тех или иных маштабов... Можно сделать так, чтоб эл-ты не менялись при масштабировании, но его запрещать не нужно